# Returning concrete class that inherits generic class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I’m trying to do the following:

```
 inline fun <reified T> getMapper(klass: Class<T>): RFMFunction<T, Event> =
    when (klass) {
      MClick::class.java -> MClickMapper
      else -> { throw RuntimeException("Unknown event type: $klass") }
    }
```

with:

```
object MClickMapper : RFMFunction<MClick, Event>()
```

but Kotlin doesn’t recognize that `MClickMapper` is a subclass of `RFMFunction<MClick, Event>`.

I tried  to add a cast `as RFMFunction<MClick, Event>` in the `when`, but that didn’t work.

The error I get is:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: RFMFunction<T, Event>
Found: ClickMapper
```

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The whole point of `reified` is to avoid passing a class to the function, you can directly do `when(T::class)`. Also `MClickMapper` is not valid syntax. Did you mean `MClickMapper()`?

Comment: `MClickMapper` is valid syntax for a Kotlin `object`

Comment: @Frank Can you post the function call?

Comment: The call is just `Mapper.getMapper(myKlass)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Kotlin doesn’t recognize that MClickMapper is a subclass of RFMFunction<MClick, Event>

That is not entirely correct. The error is `Type mismatch: inferred type is MClickMapper but RFMFunction<T, Event> was expected`.

So in fact, Kotlin refuses to consider `MClickMapper` as a subclass of `RFMFunction<T, Event>`, because `T` is provided by the *caller* of your function. The compiler doesn't go as far as knowing that `klass == MClick::class.java` means that `T == MClick`. You could technically use an unchecked cast here (since you know more than the compiler), but it should be a cast to `RFMFunction<T, Event>` (not `RFMFunction<MClick, Event>`). And then you can suppress the unchecked cast warning.

Also, as a side note, why do you use both a `KClass` and a `reified` type argument? If you reify `T`, you don't need the explicit `KClass`:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified T> getMapper(): RFMFunction<T, Event> = when (T::class) {
    MClick::class -> MClickMapper as RFMFunction<T, Event>
    else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown event type: ${T::class}")
}
```

**However, this solution is not great**, because you kinda hardcode twice the relationship between `MClickMapper` and `MClick` (in the `when` AND in the inheritance hierarchy), which means if those 2 places go out of sync you can have problems that won't be seen at compile time. It would be better to use the type information to create the mapping dynamically, so you have the mapping harcoded in a single place.

Comment: How would you create the mapping dynamically?

Comment: That depends a bit on your overall code organization. For instance if all `RFMFunction` subclasses are objects, you could "register" them in a heterogeneous map. The registering function would have type parameters that would prevent mistakes and enforce consistency with the type hierarchy, and then you can safely add your unsafe cast and suppress warning on the map access.